# Do I have to do the configuration for nservicebus on mvc4 that would be handled by the EndpointConfig.cs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nservicebus3

In the examples, most of the config is done by the dev by changing AsA_Server to AsA_Client.

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Client { }
```

However, I can't seem to do that with an ASP.NET MVC4 app.
Do I have to manually configure everything in a web environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here are links to the documentation:

- http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/894008-using-nservicebus-with-asp-net-mvc
- http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/894123-injecting-the-bus-into-asp-net-mvc-controller

You can also have a look at our sample projects for examples on how to do it, see https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/master/Samples/AsyncPagesMVC3

There is also a sample that uses MVC4 but that is against NServiceBus v4 which has not been released yet, see https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/develop/Samples/VideoStore.Msmq/VideoStore.ECommerce

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486503/configuring-nservicebus-with-asp-net-mvc4-and-structuremap shows how far I got following that documentation. Errors out with: 'MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig' configuration section is missing and could not find backup configuration section 'MsmqTransportConfig' in order to locate the error queue.

Comment: I think the example is here now https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/develop/Samples/VideoStore.Msmq/VideoStore.ECommerce